# Issue with lsof command

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, servicenow, lsof

I have a service account executing below command on a solaris server

```
lsof -iTCP -n -P -F pcnfT -z$1
```

But I receive below error message as response

```
lsof: illegal option character: z 
lsof 4.80 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/ latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ 
latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man 
usage: [-?abChlnNoOPRstUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+|-D D] [+|-f[cfgGn]] [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [-k k] [+|-L [l]] [-m m] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s] [+|-r [t]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names] 
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

What can probably cause this issue? And what are potential solutions?

Comment: According to my linux system, lsof 4.86 indicates that -z applies to Solaris 10 (and upwards). Is that your system version? If so, could you try upgrading to lsof 4.86?

Comment: The OS version as i can see is 5.9. Is it possible to resolve this without having to upgrade to 10?

Comment: Solaris 9 does not have zones. Alter your script so that the use of the parameterized `-z$1` option is not needed in that situation.

Comment: Consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this variety of the question in the future -- it's not really about *software development* (the act of writing software) per se, and that's the limit of StackOverflow's domain.

Answer (score 1):

delete -z parameter as below;

```
lsof -iTCP -n -P -F pcnfT
```

```
  -z [z]    specifies  how Solaris 10 and higher zone information is to be
        handled.

        Without a following argument - e.g., NO z - the option  speci-
        fies  that zone names are to be listed in the ZONE output col-
        umn.
```

Comment: `$1` unquoted? If you wanted to pass all arguments through, `"$@"` would make more senes. If you wanted to pass the first one through unmodified (as opposed to subject to string-splitting, glob expansion, etc), `"$1"`. If the first argument is a zone name, then it should just be deleted.